# Loosely coupled JS modules - Backbone inheritance with random file load order?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, module

Sorry for the horrible post title but it's hard to sum up.

I'm defining JS modules using the revealing module pattern in seperate files, wrapped in IFFEs, under the namespace "App". By checking for the existence of "App" in each file, they can load in any order (script tags are injected into the HTML through a build process - so probably are added in alphabetical order).

Some of the modules are purely Backbone views.

The following 2 files work fine, loaded in any order:

**app.js:**

```
App = window.App || {};

App.Main = (function(){

    var init = function(){
        var view = new App.BaseView();
    }

    return {
        init: init
    }

})();
```

**base_view.js:**

```
App = window.App || {};

App.BaseView = (function(){

    var View = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('base view init');
        }

    }); 

    return View;

})();
```

The whole app is triggered on document ready by calling App.Main.init(). I know that all modules have loaded by then - in whatever order;

However, if I want another view to *extend* BaseView, I need to know that **base_view.js** has loaded previously. The following file will not work if it was loaded *before* **base_view.js** (even though it's checking for the existence of "App" and creating it if necessary, it relies on BaseView already being defined):

**another_view.js:**

```
App = window.App || {};

App.AnotherView = (function(){

    var View = App.BaseView.extend({ //App.BaseView may not be defined!

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('base view init');
        }

    }); 

    return View;

})();
```

Is there a pattern I can use to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you're looking for a better answer than this but you could simply try wrapping it inside a sort of 'wait for it' interval loop?

```
   App = window.App || {};
   var interval = setInterval(function() {
       // get elem
       if (typeof App.BaseView == 'undefined') return;
       clearInterval(interval);

       // the rest of the code
    }, 10);
```

Comment: Yeah to be honest I'm looking for something more elegant than this - as this feels like it would impact performance, and would definitely impact readability. To be honest I'm not sure there is a way around this. I'm currently modifying my build process to specify the load order. I wanted to avoid this as it makes it cumbersome to specify many files when the project grows big.